# Returning and persisting a LinkedHashMap instead of Map in JPA Entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to persist a `LinkedHashMap` in my JPA Entity in a Spring Boot project of mine. I need this due to `LinkedHashMap` preserving insertion-order compared to other `Map` interface implementations.

In my `Comic` JPA Entity, I have the field:

```
@ElementCollection
@Column(name="price_history", nullable=true)
private Map<String, Float> priceHistory = new LinkedHashMap<String, Float>();
```

My constructor for the `Comic` entity takes a `LinkedHashMap<String,Float>` as a parameter as well.

My getter and setter methods look like this:

```
    public Map<String,Float> getPriceHistory() {
        return priceHistory;
    }

    public void setPriceHistory(Map<String,Float> priceHistory) {
        this.priceHistory = priceHistory;
    }
```

I have a method in my REST controller that allows me to edit the data for any `Comic` JPA entity instance. The following piece of code takes care of putting prices into the `priceHistory` `Map<String,Float>` object:

```
editComic.getPriceHistory().put(WordUtils.capitalizeFully(LocalDate.now().getMonth().toString() 
+ " " + LocalDate.now().getYear()), price);
editComic.setPriceHistory(editComic.getPriceHistory());
```

Is there a way for me to persist `LinkedHashMap<String,Float>` in JPA? I've tried annotating the field with `@Lob` but it causes an exception in PostgreSQL:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode.
```

Comment: That's not possible, JPA only sees a Map interface, you will have to implement the ordering yourself. The "@Lob" idea requires to serialize the whole object, and it not good practice.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. Is there any easy way to sort strings in the format "Month Year" like "June 2020" ? I'm thinking it will need a custom `Comparator` most likely - but is there a simpler alternative?

Comment: Juste use a standard `List` and the annotation `@OrderBy("date")` instead of a Map.

Comment: Ah thanks - `ArrayList` apparently keeps the insertion order so that is exactly what I need. No need to order by date in my case.

Comment: No, you need the orderBy annotation, otherwise the order will be unstable when loading data, depending on what the database judges is faster. The fact that it "seems to work" doesn't mean it does work as intended.

Comment: Yes, I had a chance to test it out further today and ordering is indeed needed. I've tested some solutions and I couldn't really get `@OrderBy` to work in my case but it appears that with `@OrderColumn` proper insertion order is maintained - I've added more data in my `ArrayList` to make sure - is `@OrderColumn` a valid substitute for `@OrderBy` in my case or am I missing something again?

Comment: `@OrderColumn` should work, the only difference is the order is managed by hibernate with a new, explicit, integer column. It may be slightly slower when updating data with reordering.